# receive DataSet (xml) on jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, web-services

i have this sample code in jQuery that connect to my WebService

sending text, and receive text. its works excellent.

```
<html  lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //var WS_URI = 'http://10.0.0.5/WS_Catalog_SQL/Service1.asmx/GetItem';    
            var WS_URI = 'http://10.0.0.5/WS_Catalog/Service1.asmx/GetItem';   
            var MAKAT ;

            function Look() {
                MAKAT = document.getElementById("txt").value.toString();
                $.ajax({
                    ServiceCallID: 1,
                    url: WS_URI,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: '{"Makat": "' + MAKAT + '"}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:
                        function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                            //document.writeln(data.d);
                            $("#RES").text((data.d).toString());
                        },
                    error:
                  function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert(textStatus);
                  }
                });
            }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body >
          <br />
          <button onclick="Look();">Press me</button>
          <input id="txt"  value="1111"/>
          <br />
          <p id="RES">res</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

my WebService code:

```
[WebMethod]
        public DataSet  GetItem(string Makat)
        {
            dsView = new DataSet();
            OpenConnection();
            SQL = "select Item,Des from MyTbl where Item = '" + Makat + "'";
            dsView = new DataSet();
            adp_SQL = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, Conn_SQL);
            adp_SQL.Fill(dsView, "MyTbl ");
            adp_SQL.Dispose();
            if (dsView.Tables["MyTbl "].Rows.Count >= 1)
            {
                return dsView;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

now i need to receive DataSet (xml),

i build WebService (in C#) that receive text and sending DataSet

but the jQuery dosent work.

i try this:

```
contentType: "text/xml",
dataType: "text",
```

and got this error:

```
POST http://10.0.0.5/WS_Catalog_SQL/Service1.asmx/GetItem 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:130
c.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:130
Look (index):14
onclick
```

I broke my head for two days and can not seem to find a solution....

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Describe what you expect to happen and what actually happens, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: i try: contentType: "text/xml",dataType: "text", -  but i got error, the function  go into the   error: section

Comment: jQuery runs your error callback because 500 is an *error code*. It's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: thanks, And how to solve it ?

Comment: For starters, you could specify `console.log` as your error callback, to print all arguments in your console, as well as inspect the request with your developer tools (such as Firebug or Chrome dev tools).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the datatype of request object :

```
contentType: "text/xml",
dataType: "text",
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i try this but i got error.  i attach the WebService code

Comment: It is internal server error i.e. May be your service is crashing. Have you tried debugging your webmethod?